# how to connect drip api in core php

Tags: php, api

I searched alot on youtube and google but failed to found. Can anyone please help me out? 
Lets assume this is my drip api token

```
gfsknncjkl
```

and my account id

```
54799636545
```

and my email id

```
abc@example.com
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first page of docs:

```
curl "api_endpoint_here" \
    -H 'User-Agent: Your App Name (www.yourapp.com)' \
    -H 'Authorization: Basic (YOUR_API_KEY)'
```

From first git search:

[PHP library for making token-based API requests against Drip.](https://github.com/drewm/drip)